# Myspell and different variants of Spanish

Tags: vocabulario, diferencias-regionales

This is somewhat computer related as well.

If one installs the myspell package in Ubuntu, it would download files for Spanish Spanish, and files for e.g. Argentinian Spanish would be just symlinks to it. Which means that as far as the spellchecker is concerned, there's only one Spanish.

I wonder if it's usable like that? If not, maybe you are aware of myspell dictionaries for different variants of Spanish and could provide a link?

Now yes, it's about software, but it needs an answer from actual speakers, so I decided to post it here, not at Stack Overflow or Super User.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is whether it's OK to use the same spellchecker dictionaries for all regional variants of Spanish, and if no, where could I find more relevant dictionaries. This is a software related question which only native speakers can answer, hence spanish.stackexchange.

Comment: It's not really a Spanish-related question; it's more of a linguistic question: Do different dialects have different languages?  The exact same question can be asked of English, or any other language with multiple dialects.

Comment: There are many spell checkers available, many open source, which offer regional dictionaries.

Comment: And these dictionaries can be obtained where?

Comment: That's really beyond the scope of this site.  I would start with google. I know Mozilla has such dictionaries.  So does OpenOffice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> as far as the spellchecker is concerned, there's only one Spanish.

That sounds true to me. The differences among Spanish variants are relevant in vocabulary, grammar and pronunciation; but there are no differences in spelling, as far as I know.

It's true, however, that vocabulary and grammar differences could have some small influence on a speller, e.g.: *"sabés"* would be acceptable in Spanish with *voseo*, while in other regions the speller should suggest instead "*sabes*" or "*sabéis*".

Comment: But the spelling is different in "sabés" because of it's actually a different word ;)